# How do I move gigabytes of data from my computer to my phone's SD card?

Tags: data-transfer, mtp

I'm trying to put my music collection (~37GB) onto my android phone's SD card via USB cable and MTP. It has to go on the card, because my phone's internal memory is not capacious enough.

I've tried drag and drop, rsync, cp, etc. (OS is Linux, phone is Galaxy S8)

Once I get about ~15 GB of data in the directory I can't even ls it or look at it in the GUI file browser, much less add more. Attempting to do anything at that point seems to crash the filesystem driver.

Googling the problem seems to be useless, I just get a bunch of basic tutorials on transferring data with no mention of problems or scope.

Is there some known way to accomplish this short of yanking out the SD card and loading things onto it directly? Am I just weird for trying to copy such a large amount of data via USB/MTP?

Comment: Although you seems to have solved this problem by using Windows, did you try using adb (setting up a script to copy-paste individual files) or running a server say FTP, on Android and than copy-pasting into it? adb is slow but FTP could be faster using USB tethering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the SD card in the computer and drag & drop there. I have a SD slot and use a uSD to SD card adapter. Try dragging smaller chunks vs all at once.  I have a 64GB card and drag 20-30 folders at a time, each folder being a complete album. Getting ready to install a 128GB card and do it all again to hold about half my music collection.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that (and have in the past) but that means that every single time I get new music I have to go through the whole rigamarole all over again.

Comment: Then only do it for the very large transfers. Use USB to let the PC see the phone as external hard drive for transferring an album or two. For hundreds of albums, direct to card is better.

Comment: The problem is that like I said, once there's so much in that directory on the card I can't even look at it without a crash, much less modify. I can't even *rename* something.

Comment: You need a better card then, sounds like it's on the way out.  What kind is it? I'd pop mine put of my LG (ThinQ G7?) and tell you the brand/model if I had the little widget that goes in the hole to release it with me. I can tell you I have 15.3GB free, 43.3GB used on my 64GB card. It's the same card I had in my Samsung Galaxy SIII for ages. I've deleted everything and reloaded it since then, the music app I had was showing double entries for a lot of stuff, reformatting and reloading seemed to be the only thing that fixed it.  40+ GB of music takes quite a while.

Comment: I don't doubt that: even moving it to a flash drive takes a couple hours on USB2.0. And it may well be an issue with the card, it was a cheapo I got off amazon. But I've been using it for a long time with no issues until I deleted and tried to reload my music collection.

Comment: I got it done with no issues on a borrowed windows 10 box. Not happy about it, but it got done. Thanks for trying to help, gave an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it no problems on a borrowed Windows 10 box. Not that such an answer is very pleasing to a linux enthusiast.